A movie about a guy who made contact with aliens and lost his sleep
The movie is about a man who made a contact with aliens or something (I don't remember) and has lost his sleep as a result. So he is awake 24 hours per day, he reads and constructs a lot of weird stuff. I think I he lives in countryside, I definitely remember fields in the movie. Also, I remember that he helps to heal someone at some point. I'm almost sure that closer to the end of the film he gets back to normal life and loses his special abilities.

Pretty sure it's an American movie.

You might be talking about Phenomenon (1996).

 [George] pauses to watch a strange light in the sky, then collapses for a few seconds in the middle of the deserted street. In the days and weeks that follow, George finds his IQ and consciousness expanding dramatically, and develops telekinetic abilities. 

One of the effects is lack of sleep and memorizing everything he reads (he learns how to speak portuguese in a couple of hours).




Yes, this is it! Thank you.
